# How do I mock a SessionContext injected via @Resource in Java-EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I'm getting the following `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at FacadeBean.createRegistration(FacadeBean.java:389)
```

Under `FacadeBean.java`:

```
private SessionContext context

public CreateRegistrationResponse createRegistration() {
  try {
    // snip
  } catch (DataAccessException de){
    context.setRollbackOnly(); //---------line 389
    throw new ServiceException("Error");        
  }
}
```

Test class

```
@Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
public void testCreateRegistrationError() throws ServiceException {
    doThrow(DataAccessException.class).when(mockRegistrationPeristenceImpl).create(any(Registration.class));
    facadeBeanTest.createRegistration(RegistrationFacadeMock.getCreateRegistrationRequest());
}
```

Could someone tell me how to mock the below line, so that I can ignore this `context.setRollbackOnly();`

```
public class FacadeBean {
  public FacadeBean() {}
  @Resource
  private SessionContext context
}
```

Comment: I tried both suppress and mock, doesn't work ,suppress(field(FacadeBean.class, "context"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to change the class to use [**method injection**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html#bncjm) instead of **field injection**.

In other words, in your real class, change this:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext context;
```

into this:

```
private SessionContext context;

@Resource
public void setSessionContext(SessionContext sessionContext) {
 this.sessionContext = sessionContext;
}
```

Then, once you've done that, you can inject a mock using your unit test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  // You probably have other code here already
  facadeBean.setSessionContext(mock(SessionContext.class));
}
```

You may have an issue with JAXB if you do this, though; if that happens, read this question: [SessionContext Injection using @Resource annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5538785/1768232)

---

If you can't change the code, you can probably access the field via reflection, doing something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  Field sessionContextField = FacadeBean.class.getDeclaredField("context");
  sessionContextField.setAccessible(true);
  sessionContextField.set(beanObject, mock(SessionContext.class));
}
```

Comment: right now I don't have a scope to change existing code,only write JUnit/mockito without modify existing code.Pls suggest whether I can suppress that field?

Comment: @Durron597, based on the example, what would beanObject represent?